# How to use the word alias

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

How do I convey that the "Object" can be used instead of "ObjectInGroup"?

My current guess is: "Use the alias Object instead of ObjectInGroup". Is there any mistake in this sentence that I am not aware of?

Specifically, I'm unsure of the comma usage like "Use the alias Object, instead of ObjectInGroup"

Comment: There’s only one comma in your entire post, and it seems to be fine where it is. Are you proposing to insert one or more commas?

Comment: Yes, in the sentence. I'll add the sentence

Comment: What are you hoping to discover, please? 

Doesn't "(Use the alias) Object instead of ObjectInGroup" suggest using a real count noun, such as car or vehicle, in place of a non-count concept such as traffic or transports?